# What is this nine tined tool used for?

Tags: identify-a-tool

Nine fixed flat springy metal tines, like a rake that roguely jumped out of the factory line, sallying forth into the public realm before its time. The handle telescopes out to about 4' in length, which is about right for itching a residential ceiling before the skim coat sets up.  My grandad used to say a tool is in the eye of the beholder, but this looks factory made for some swath of beholders, whatever that intended purpose was, ...... which was what ?

[image: tined tool]

Comment: Any manufacturing marks or anything similar?

Comment: One of the shadows looks to have a bend in it. Are you sure all the tines are perfectly straight? Does it look like maybe the tines had been straightened?

Comment: Good catch, @UnhandledExcepSean! The 4th shadow from the bottom does seem to have a distinct "rake shaped" bend in it. Maybe the tines look straight simply because of the angle of the picture.

Answer (score 5):

It's a shrub rake used for gardening.

> A shrub rake is built very much like a leaf rake. It has a smaller fan of tines, though, allowing it better access to the ground beneath shrubbery, around fencing, and in other tight areas of your landscape... some handles telescope in and out, a function that may be handy for reaching around shrubs.
>
> (from [Bob Villa](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/rake-types/))

Based off of [this product listing](https://www.pricelessproducts.com/item/Telescopic-Shrub-Rake-9-tines/308/) which looks to be identical.

Comment: Your product list is _almost_ identical. As noted in other comments, the OPs product doesn't have the bent ends that are shown in both your links. It does seem really close, though, and maybe this is a straight-tinned version of a shrub rake...

Comment: Hmm... based on the comment by @UnhandledExcepSean on the question (which contradicts his comment here), I do now see a distinct rake-shaped bend in one of the shadows. Maybe I'll have to retract my previous comment!

Comment: The tines appear to bend at about 1-1/2", which corresponds to the linked product. There's a clear pattern of mild rust where they're worn.

Comment: Based on the bent shadow, I don't think the OP's description is accurate and it does have bent/angled tines and is a rake. +1